# disable my Tabbar & Navigationbar of the screen on Waiting/Loading imageview

Tags: ios4, view, uinavigationbar, loading, uitabbar

I am working on an web service based application. I need Loading/waiting imageview that should **disable my Tabbar & Navigationbar** of the screen till Loading of web service . The issue when I keep the imageview that contains the waiting animation over in my viewcontroller, it disables only self.view. Can anybody please tell what i went wrong?

Regards,
sathish

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place? This seems like a poor user experience. The user should almost always have the option to cancel.

Comment: Hi justin till loading of web service because If press back button when loading it crashes to avoid it i go with disabling the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can either hide the tab bar by `tabbar.hidden=YES` or if you want to remove the tab bar from the window and put it again, you need to release the tab bar and then allocate it again...
But releasing the tab bar will make your app crash, so before releasing the tab bar remove it from super view.

```
[TabBarController.view removeFromSuperview];
[TabBarController release];
```

then allocate it again and put it on the window

```
[self createTabBar]; // createTabBar is a function creating a tab bar
[self.window addSubview:TabBarController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```